# Dating photo of train station depot in Mertzon, Texas?

Tags: 20th-century, photo-identification, photo-dating, texas

I've got a photo of what I think is a postcard showing the train depot in Mertzon, Texas:

[image]

I'm wondering what the likely date is?

Comment: There are more clues on the other side of the card, in an eBay listing: https://www.ebay.com/itm/264272422057

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The railroad [started service in Mertzon](https://tshaonline.org/handbook/online/articles/hlm60) in 1911.  So that's the oldest your station can be (give or take a couple of years).

Your goal now is to find out when it was actually built and if it was rebuilt.  Years other features were added.  And also see if you can find pictures of it at various times and compare the wear.

Turns out part of it was rebuilt.

> On Feb. 28, 1938, a tornado blew the south warehouse down and took the
>   roof off the railroad depot. ([ref](http://archive.gosanangelo.com/news/columnists/of-preston-dudley-and-a-life-spent-outdoors-in-west-texas-ep-442072092-357687221.html/))

Find pictures of that roof before and after 1938 and that will tell you if the postcard comes from before or after that time.  Then keep going.